# Display More Added Columns by the user In Report viewer

Tags: c#, sql, database, reportviewer

I created a windows form application using c# and sql database.
At the run time, I was able to add/delete columns in the datagridveiw and get the data updated. This way, when I reopen the application the data are saved, I was able to get a report viewer that I designed statically with the wizard. However it only shows the columns that were added in the design phase not the run time.

How can I display the modifications that occur to the data (adding or deleting columns) at the run time in the report viewer?

Suppose I designed the report to have three columns Name, LastName, money, and get the report successfully at the runtime, and then I added some new columns say (Age,Country)
during the run time. When I try to get the report I only get 3 columns (Name, LastName, Money) with updated Rows But not added columns.

Comment: I edited your post to make it clearer. Also, no need to flatter us.

Comment: Okay Thank You so Much, Best Reqards

Answer (score 0):

I just solved the same problem. I was searching for a few days in internet but I couldn't find a good answer for it. So I hope my post will help somebody to overcome the same problem.

All you need to do - just define manually the connection, refill the dataset and bind the source to reportviewer. Here is my project example:

using Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms;

```
private void ReportForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
    conn.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=D:\GD Robotics\VisualProjects\GDPolin\GDPolin\PolinaDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30";
    conn.Open();
    SqlDataAdapter reportDBTableAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM  [ReportDB]", conn);
    DataTable polinaDBDataSet = new DataTable();
    reportDBTableAdapter.Fill(polinaDBDataSet);
    conn.Close();

    this.reportViewer1.Reset();
    this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
    this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = @"D:\GD Robotics\VisualProjects\GDPolin\GDPolin\Report1.rdlc";
    ReportDataSource rds = new ReportDataSource("DataSet1", polinaDBDataSet);//"DataSet1" is the name of your dataset. Go to .rdlc form>VIEW>Report Data>"Right click on dataset">Dataset Properties
    this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds);
    this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
}
```